# Как перевести на русский дату?

Tags: php

```
 $monthName = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month));
```

выводит на англе

Answer (score 1):

У тебя есть 2 пути:
1. Использовать setlocale (что не всегда гут)
2. Определить массив с названиями месяцев на русском и использовать так

$ruMonthName = ['январь', 'февраль' и т.д.];

> $monthName = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month));

если в $month у тебя передается числовое значение месяца, то, сделай просто так

```
echo $ruMonthName[ $month ];
```

как то так.

Comment: и почитай внимательно тут [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32935191/english-dates-to-russian-with-php)

Comment: оки, пасиб  )))___)